Different results for the same function on the same data
I was using version R 4.3.0 and PMCMRplus 1.9.7 and got the following results:
> frdAllPairsConoverTest(y = dados_CM$media, groups = dados_CM$ano, blocks = dados_CM$cidade, p.adjust.method = 'none')$p.value
2010        2011       2012       2013       2014      2015      2016      2017
2011 0.1739243          NA         NA         NA         NA        NA        NA        NA
2012 0.3037385 0.729151187         NA         NA         NA        NA        NA        NA
2013 0.2543788 0.817315192 0.90801019         NA         NA        NA        NA        NA
2014 0.8173152 0.254378831 0.42172736 0.35950609         NA        NA        NA        NA
2015 0.7291512 0.092609917 0.17392433 0.14205988 0.56475282        NA        NA        NA
2016 0.5647528 0.058667311 0.11513103 0.09260992 0.42172736 0.8173152        NA        NA
2017 0.1739243 0.009869479 0.02184836 0.01683992 0.11513103 0.3037385 0.4217274        NA
2019 0.1420599 0.007509960 0.01683992 0.01291952 0.09260992 0.2543788 0.3595061 0.9080102
> packageVersion("PMCMRplus")
[1] ‘1.9.7’

When updating both, the results changed considerably, R 4.3.3 and PMCMRplus 1.9.10
> frdAllPairsConoverTest(y = dados_CM$media, groups = dados_CM$ano, blocks = dados_CM$cidade, p.adjust.method = 'none')$p.value
2010        2011       2012       2013       2014      2015      2016      2017
2011 0.02116321           NA           NA           NA          NA         NA        NA        NA
2012 0.07666301 5.432585e-01           NA           NA          NA         NA        NA        NA
2013 0.05086009 6.846374e-01 0.8388708647           NA          NA         NA        NA        NA
2014 0.68463739 5.086009e-02 0.1630949335 1.131195e-01          NA         NA        NA        NA
2015 0.54325852 5.086588e-03 0.0211632105 1.332707e-02 0.314299607         NA        NA        NA
2016 0.31429961 1.867770e-03 0.0082807938 5.086588e-03 0.163094934 0.68463739        NA        NA
2017 0.02116321 4.922086e-05 0.0002360732 1.399588e-04 0.008280794 0.07666301 0.1630949        NA
2019 0.01332707 2.924623e-05 0.0001399588 8.296711e-05 0.005086588 0.05086009 0.1131195 0.8388709
> packageVersion("PMCMRplus")
[1] ‘1.9.10’

Some help?

Bug fix - See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PMCMRplus/news.html
